# Path's storing in config files?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, path

Looking at a simple config entry :

What is the best practice decision when saving path's ? with trailing slash such as :

```
<add key="aaa" value="\\dsFileSrv\Documents\Public\RX\DATA\Source\"/>
```

or

```
<add key="aaa" value="\\dsFileSrv\Documents\Public\RX\DATA\Source"/>
```

*p.s. I know I can use Path.Combine to eliminate this conflict.*

But still , there must be a best-overall-decision as a starting point..

Comment: By adding backslash you are telling the potential human config file reader  that this is more likely a path to a directory and not to a file even if key has non-descriptive name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking with myself , ( and after reading the answer/s)

I think that  in order for the onfig file to be more "human readable" and "more understandable" -

specifying with slash is a better choice. ( cause in c:\a\1 , 1 can be file).

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what the framework itself uses...

`Environment.CurrentDirectory`

Output:

`C:\Users\rotem\Desktop`

Therefore, I would say without trailing slashes.

**edit**
Having said that, there is no real harm in including trailing backslashes if you are using `Path.Combine`, and as mentioned in the comments, it may communicate better that this is guaranteed to be a directory and not a file with no extension.

Comment: +1 nice ! but there is a logic-difference (IMHO) between a result which yields path vs starting point to begin with. ( don't know why - and dont ask me also :-) )

Comment: @RoyiNamir Can you explain what you mean by starting point? (oh sorry, you said not to ask you :))

Comment: A variable which future elements location  will be build on.

Comment: in your sample , Desktop can be a file. I think by adding a slash u r excplicit showing it is a  folder.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I agree that adding the backslash 'can't hurt', and is more readable to someone browsing the raw config file.